# rails3 user can only vote once per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rate, vote

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :image_id, :rate, :user_id
 belongs_to :image
 belongs_to :user
 validate :user_can_rate_after_one_day

 before_save :default_values

def default_values
 self.rate ||=0
end

protected
  def user_can_rate_after_one_day
    r=Rate.where(:image_id =>image_id, :user_id=> user_id).order("created_at DESC").limit(1)

    if( (Time.now - 1.day) < r[0].created_at)
      self.errors.add(:rate,"you can only vote once per day") 
    else
      return
    end
  end
end
```

I have one rate model, and i want the user can only rate once per day. i write the user_can_rate_after_one_day method to validte it. If i delete the function, the user can rate many time, if i add this function, user can not rate it. Anyone knows what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you saying that your validation method isn't working properly? That it won't allow a user to rate at all, even if they haven't rated something already today?

Comment: Are you sure you have no errors on the console;

Comment: well, let me explain it.  the method user_can_rate_after_one_day should works like that: when there is no rate, it should validate true. if there is rate and the rate is not older than one day, it should invalidate. i write the if condition as that "if( r[0] !=nil && (Time.now  < (r[0].created_at + 1.day)))", when there is no record, i think the condition should be false, then the validation pass, but the result it that, the condition always true and the validation always fail.

Comment: @normalocity [if i write it like if( r[0].created_at < 1.day.ago ), the user can vote many times. I am a bit confused.]

Comment: You're right, **I had it backwards** in my head. :S Sorry about that.

Comment: if i write "( r[0] !=nil && (Time.now  < (r[0].created_at + 1.day)))", then all condition is true, if i write "( r[0] !=nil && (Time.now  > (r[0].created_at + 1.day)))" then all the condition is false. means that the "&&" does not work, strange..

Comment: couldn´t you write:
return if r.length == 0, and then your if-else? I think that should work..

Comment: hi,all, thanks for your effort. I just found that i have something wrong with my controller. Here is the final solution:           protected
   def user_can_rate_after_one_day
 
 r=Rate.find_by_image_id_and_user_id(image_id, user_id)
 if( r!=nil and (Time.now  < (r.updated_at + 1.day)))
   self.errors.add(:rate,"you can only vote once per day")
 end
  end

Answer (score 1):

I have also the same type of problem. I tried to create an application in which a particular user can add standup for the current day only. I wrote the code in my controller create action. The logic is almost similar to your question, but I found one issue in your code due to which your date is not compared properly `Time.now - 1.day` return in this format `2018-01-22 11:24:23 +0545` and `standup[0].created_at` return in this format `Mon, 22 Jan 2018 08:58:57 UTC +00:00`.
So, to solve this issue, I converted both the date in same format i.e 
`(Time.now - 1.day).strftime('%F %H:%M:%S') < standup[0].created_at.strftime('%F %H:%M:%S')` which returns `true`, and the code works.

It might be helpful to other viewers as well.